# How to boot chrome os not chromium inside a virtual machine and without owning a chromebook?

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, virtualization, google-chrome-os

I tried to download an official oem recovery image with https://dl.google.com/dl/edgedl/chromeos/recovery/chromeos_9000.91.0_sentry_recovery_stable-channel_mp.bin.zip but the kernel images which can be booted through uefi can only launch the recovery process which loop reboots *(remember chromebooks uses coreboot not bios to load kernel images directly in a special checksumed format not supported by grub and lilo)*. The virtual machine had access to a skylake cpu, so I doubt any illegal instructions are involved.
Maybe the checksumed kernel images that are not on any fileystem can boot chrome os instead of recovery, but their format requires coreboot. I am unable to compile coreboot for qemu due to lot of errors, nor I did find a pre built bios image.

An alternate option would be to download an oem update through the update server since I can get the auths key from a recovery image, but despite reading the source I am unable to see what a suitable curl command would look like.

I do not care about the virtual machine engine, it may be qemu as well as HyperV. The aim is to get chrome os working without purshasing any hardware.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you can do that. Users on [/r/chrultrabook](https://www.reddit.com/r/chrultrabook/) were able to install other operating systems either by booting through the legacy boot capability/slot and keeping Chrome OS or by modifying uefi boot stub or replacing the entire firmware, thus breaking Chrome OS.  Booting Chrome OS as you intend (by satisfying the dependencies as far as necessary) would be great but so far only very little progress has been made which involves making modifications to the image/bootloader* thus breaking the boot chain and the possibility to receive updates. That's all I can tell you right now.

You may ask at the subreddit (I think it was ReddestDream) or [reverseengineering.stackexchange.com](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/) if you really want to get your hands dirty and have experience with firmwares. I'd really appreciate that, but so far I think the answer is that it can't be done.

- Chrome OS has it's very own bootloader called Depthcharge ([1](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/platform/depthcharge/), [2](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=sites&srcid=Y2hyb21pdW0ub3JnfGRldnxneDo4MzM3YjM4MWJjZjBjZTI), [3](https://libreboot.org/docs/depthcharge/))

Comment: There [use to be a script for turning a chromium ᴏꜱ into a chrome ᴏꜱ](http://goo.gl/4suhf) through Google update servers, but I don’t know were to download it. In theory, there’s an open source version of the Google’s patched coreboot for qemu, but in practice, I’m failing to compile it as well as depthcharge. The best solution is to find someone willing to send a copy of it’s eᴍᴍc  drive as well as it’s coreboot.